# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main -Android 5.1

Tags: java, android

When I try to run my simple project of cal app has been a stop on device.
it shows me E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main error

test on Huawei Y3II android 5.1

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.testcalc, PID: 2682
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{3c966173 VFED..CL ........ 80,96-400,164 #7f07008e app:id/txtInput1}"
>           at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
>           at com.example.testcalc.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20270)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5660)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)

```
    package com.example.testcalc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //define Variables
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
    TextView ans;
    EditText text1,text2;
    int no1,no2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txtadd);//number 1 = +
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txtsubs);//number 1 = -
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txtDiv);//number 1 = /
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txtmulti);//number 1 = *

        ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtans);//answer =  ans

        text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput1);
        text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput2);


        //            +

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                no1=Integer.parseInt(text1.toString());
                no2=Integer.parseInt(text2.toString());
                ans.setText(Integer.toString(no1+no2));

            }
        });
        //               -

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                no1=Integer.parseInt(text1.toString());
                no2=Integer.parseInt(text2.toString());
                ans.setText(Integer.toString(no1-no2));

            }
        });

        //               /

        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                no1=Integer.parseInt(text1.toString());
                no2=Integer.parseInt(text2.toString());
                ans.setText(Integer.toString(no1/no2));

            }
        });

        //               *

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                no1=Integer.parseInt(text1.toString());
                no2=Integer.parseInt(text2.toString());
                ans.setText(Integer.toString(no1*no2));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text1` and `text2` are Editfields. `toString()` does not return the content of the field. So `Integer.parseInt(text1.toString());` can not parse the value.

Thats why you get

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{3c966173 VFED..CL ........ 80,96-400,164 #7f07008e app:id/txtInput1}"

change to:

```
no1=Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString());
```

But take care, you get the same exception if the value in the edit field has not an int value

Comment: Thanks. It's working!